# 4D plot surface does'nt display the colors of my 4th dimension

Tags: python, matplotlib, 4d

I've been trying de plot 4D figures of aerosols emissions in the atmosphere with X = Longitude, Y = latitude, Z = Injection Heigh of aerosols and cbar = Emissions quantity.

The following lines do the job but the cbar datas seems to be 0 everywhere.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
X, Y = np.meshgrid(lons2,lats2)
Z = Inj
C=Emi
scamap = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='inferno')
fcolors = scamap.to_rgba(C)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, facecolors=fcolors, cmap='inferno')
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=10e-8)
fig.colorbar(scamap,norm=norm)
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see, it's all black.

Do you have any suggestion, or another way to plot those data ? Maybe scatter could be a solution but I can't figure it out.

Have a good day,

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize the colors, like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
x = y = np.linspace(-2, 2)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.cos(X**2 + Y**2)
# color values
C = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
cmap = cm.inferno
norm = Normalize(vmin=np.amin(C), vmax=np.amax(C))
# create face colors from a colormap and normalized color values
fcolors = cmap(norm(C))
scamap = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, facecolors=fcolors, cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(scamap)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I guess I have too much values to be displayed, they seems to be hidden by the black color as there is much more null values in my dataframe.
Thank you for your help anyway.